# Exam FM problem. Bonds

Tags: finance, percentages, actuarial-science

the following problem is what I am working on.

> Suzan can buy a zero coupon bond that will pay $1000$ at the end of $12$ years and is currently selling for $624.60$. Instead she purchases a $6\%$ bond with coupons payable semi-annually that will pay $1000$ at the end of $10$ years.  If she pays $X$ she will earn the same annual effective interest rate as the zero coupon bond.  Calculate X.

I understand that the effective interest rate per 1/2 a year is $1.98\%$ from the zero coupon bond, but I am not understanding what the other coupon does.

Is the redemption fee $1000$?  Is the Future value of the bond $1000$?  Either way I did not get the correct answer which is $1167$.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Future value is always par removing extreme default events of a business.

Comment: So, I am thinking that if $X$ is what Suzan is going to pay, then the redemption value is also $X$.  But if that is the case then she would receive $1.03X=1000$ which does not make sense.

Comment: Are you saying that $X=578.34(1-(.03-.0198)a_{\overline{20}_.0198})$ ?

Comment: I appreciate that.  I'm more confused where the 1000 comes into play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With zero coupon bond, using your calculator, when $n = 24$ (bi-annual payments), $i = {}?$, $PV = 624.6$ and $FV = -1000$, we have that $i = 3.96$ which is the bi-annual interest so the interest would be $I = 3.96(2) = 7.92$.

With the 10 year bound, we have that we receive two coupon payments a year totalling $\$60$ so that is two payments of $\$30$. In your calculator, you would enter:
\begin{align}
n &= 20\\
i &= 3.96\\
PV &= \\
PMT &= -30\\
FV &= -1000
\end{align}
Yields the answer you don't agree with. Note that both PMT and FV must carry the same sign since you receive the FV and the PMTs.

Comment: This is the part that I don't understand.  Why do we know that we receive $30$ in each conversion period?  I thought that the coupon we receive depends on how much we pay at firs, so doesn't it have to be $Xr=X(.03)$ ?

Comment: @hyg17 your problem states that the coupon is $6\%$ and par is taking to $\$1000$ unless specified otherwise. So we know for sure $\$60$ a year is received. With bi-annual, it is $60/2=30$.

Comment: Okay so please let me clarify this.  In this problem, the par value $F=1000$, the redemption fee is also $C=1000$. The coupon rate $r=6\%$ and the yield rate is what I calculated.  $X$ is just the present value of this bond.  Am I right?

Comment: @hyg17 if that is what you call X, I am used to labeling it as PV.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am studying this alone and I see many different ways to represent present values, sometimes its $X$ some times it's $P$ or $PV$.  I was not sure what I was looking for in this problem, so I have used $X$.  Anyhow, thank you very much.

Comment: @hyg17 on the exam, you should be able to use the TI BA 2 Plus, correct? If so, make sure you practice with it prior since it can do all these calculations

Comment: I actually bought a TI BA II+ for this occasion, and honestly it is so confusing to use because it does not follow the ordinary algebraic approach such like TI 30X IIS does.  I am actually thinking that I would be better off with the latter one because it is much easier to use and I make less errors.  The only problem I would have is calculating interest rates given the other values, and since it is multiple choice I would still be able to check it.  I just wish there were calculators that is kind of like the mixture of these two calculators.

Comment: @hyg17 TI83 and 89 can handle finance really well but they are both expensive and probably not allowed.

Comment: I could simply use a graphing calculator then, right? lol anyhow, I really appreciate your help.